# How do query a pardot prospect by email address

Tags: pardot

I think i must be missing something simple, however I have looked through the documentation here:
http://developer.pardot.com/kb/api-version-3/prospects/

and I cannot find a simple way to query for prospect based on their email address.  None of the filters support it.  Is there something I'm missing here?  Or is there a different API I should be using to query for a Prospect and get their various attributes.

Answer (score 2):

ahh. I found it. Here is the URL in case anyone needs it:
https://pi.pardot.com/api/prospect/version/3/do/read?email=

Comment: did you mean `/api/prospect/version/3/do/read/email/<email>`?